# A European Mail Hosting Provider

Tags: email, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

What are reliable e-mail Hosting Providers in Europe (Laws). It's important that they exist already for some time (no Newcomers), or are used by bigger companies.

One Provider I know is [SwissMail](http://swissmail.org), but I would like to have some diversity. I don't need the cheapest, but it would be good if you can suggest providers, which you have experience with.

Comment: Can you please elaborate exactly what you are looking for. Or just any EU mail hosting provider?

Comment: It should be under proper Data Retention Laws, should be safe to use in mission critical business. We need just the basic Imap or Pop Access, as we download the mails from the servers to a local server. But Question is already closed, although I don't see any similar Question on the whole site.

Comment: The question that is mentioned as Duplicate here, says they don't want subjective information, but I'm looking for experience, not facts. (Facts I can read on a website of the hosting provider).